# Help with understanding $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n)$ manifolds (?)

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, reference-request

I've recently started studying the square root velocity function representation of real functions and curves. Authors of the papers I have do not explain the underlying mathematical concepts and I couldn't google any relevant texts. For example they consider a certain subset of $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n)$ (the vector-valued analogue of the standard $L^2(\mathbb{R})$), namely a unit sphere under a certain norm. Now they take a manifold-like structure of that subspace for granted and start constructing tangent spaces, providing Riemannian structure and talking about geodesics.

I don't understand how the manifold structure here is obvious as the commonly known differential geometry theory applies only to finite-dimensional spaces. This one is clearly infinitely-dimensional. Could you suggest me any introductory reading that could help me understand it?

EDIT: After seeing that there is a very similar questions with answers I have one thing to add: the accepted answer gives a link to an interesting book but it's unclear to me if $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^n)$ is convenient.

Comment: Actually mostly a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295358/how-are-infinite-dimensional-manifolds-most-commonly-treated?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions you may want to check (assuming there is a math library available to you):

Abraham, Marsden, Ratiu: Manifolds, Tensor Analysis and Applications.

Deimlings Nonlinear Functional Analyis.

Serge Lang: Real Analysis

Klingenbergs Differential Geometry. The deGruyter book.

Each book covers different aspects. There may be more recent introductory texts, but regardless of that: judging from what you explain you already know: a *lot* of time and patience.

Comment: Thanks but I've already taken real analysis and functional analysis courses and have studied introductory topology and differential geometry on my own. Judging by tables of contents these books do not consider infinitely-dimensional manifolds. And I'm actually doing applied mathematics so I'm mostly interested in how much of standard differential geometry translates to the infinitely-dimensional case. What breaks and what holds.

Comment: @matb The list has been compiled with a focus on books which _do_ treat infinite dimensional manifolds. Each of them does.